# Populating multiple datagridviews from a single 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I recently posted a question on how to populate a 2 dimensional array with data from 7 datagridviews,
each with 7 rows x 5 columns.
***Enigmativity*** supplied me with a piece of code that worked great, many thanks.

```
public string[,] myGridData = new string[50, 5]; 
//49 data rows, last row (50) contains version number

var dgvs = new[] { dgv6, dgv5, dgv4, dgv3, dgv2, dgv1, dgv0, };

for (var i = 0; i < dgvs.Length; i++)
{
  for (int rows = 0; rows < 7; rows++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
     myGridData[rows + i * 7, col] =   dgvs[i].Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
    }
  }
}
```

I now need a way to reverse the procedure and populate the 7 datagridviews from the original array.

I know how to populate a single datagridview from a 2d array, but not sure how to populate all 7 grids.
The code I have been using to fill 1 grid is:

```
//Populate Single DataViewGrid
var rowCount = myGridData.GetLength(0);
var rowLength = myGridData.GetLength(1);

dgv1.ColumnCount = 5;

for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount - 1; ++rowIndex)
{
   var row = new DataGridViewRow();

   for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowLength; ++columnIndex)
   {
      row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
      {
        Value = myGridData[rowIndex, columnIndex]
      });
   }

   dgv1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like populating the 2d array, you need to iterate through the 7 `DataGridView` controls. Nesting your code within that loop, you then change how far your inner loop iterates. Instead of iterating `rowCount - 1`, filling one `DataGridView` with all 49 rows, you only iterate over the next 7 rows. By moving `rowIndex` outside of the outermost loop, it will "remember" the next index as you progress through each view.

```
var rowCount = myGridData.GetLength(0);
var rowLength = myGridData.GetLength(1);
int rowIndex = 0;

var dgvs = new[] { dgv6, dgv5, dgv4, dgv3, dgv2, dgv1, dgv0, };

for (int i = 0; i < dgvs.Length; i++)
{
    var dgv = dgvs[i];
    dgv.ColumnCount = 5;

    for (int taken = 0; taken < 7; ++taken, ++rowIndex)
    {
        var row = new DataGridViewRow();

        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < rowLength; ++columnIndex)
        {
            row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
            {
                Value = myGridData[rowIndex, columnIndex]
            });
        }

        dgv.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

If it makes you feel better, you can modify the inner loop to:

```
for (int taken = 0; taken < 7 && rowIndex < rowCount - 1; ++taken, ++rowIndex)
```

But honestly it will still execute the same and is creating an additional logic check for each iteration.

Comment: Thanks OhBeWise, your code seems to do the job great!!